# What are the currently supported redis versions? (latest stable 6.0.6)

Tags: redis, lifecycle

[Redis release cycle page](https://redis.io/topics/releases) states

> Support
> Older versions are not supported as we try very hard to make the Redis API mostly backward compatible. Upgrading to newer versions is usually trivial.
>
> For example, if the current stable release is 2.6.x, we accept bug reports and provide support >for the previous stable release (2.4.x), but not for older ones such as 2.2.x.
>
> When 2.8 becomes the current stable release, the 2.6.x will be the oldest supported release.

Does this mean that currently supported versions are 6.0 (latest stable version 6.0.6) and 5.0 (previous stable version 5.0.9), and older versions such as (4.0.x, 3.2.x, 2.8.x) are not supported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I think your interpretation is correct